# Flask-Bootstrapで日本語を記入するとUTF-8エラーが発生する

Tags: flask

FlaskとBootstrapでWeb開発を行っているのですが、Bootstrapのコードの中に日本語を記入するとUnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x82 in position 1303: invalid start byteというようなエラーが発生します。

どうすれば、日本語で書いてもエラーが発生しないようになるのでしょうか。

誰かご回答をお願いします。

ちなみにコードはこちらです。

```
{% extends "index.html" %}

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
{% block content %}
<div class="container">
<div class="card card-container w-75 mx-auto">
 <form method="POST" action="">
 {{ form.hidden_tag()}}
 <fieldset class="form-group">
 <center>
 <img id="profile-img" class="profile-img-card img-responsive " src="//ssl.gstatic.com/accounts/ui/avatar_2x.png" style="border-radius:100%"/>
 </center>
   <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Join Today</legend>
   <div class="form-group">
   {{form.username.label(class="form-control-label")}}
   {{ form.username(class="form-control w-75 mx-auto")}}
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
     {{ form.email.label(class="form-control-label")}}
     {{ form.email(class="form-control w-75 mx-auto")}}
   </div>

<div class="form-group">
     {{ form.password.label(class=" form-control-label")}}
     {{ form.password(class="form-control w-75 mx-auto")}}
   </div>

<div class="form-group">
{{ form.confirm_password.label(class="form-control-label")}}
{{ form.confirm_password(class="form-control w-75 mx-auto")}}
   </fieldset>
   <div class="form-group">
   {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-block btn-primary w-75 mx-auto") }}
   </div>
 </form>
 </div>

 <div class="border-top pt-3">
 <small class="text-muted">
 すでにアカウントを持っていますか？<a class="ml-2" href="{{url_for('login')}}">ログイン</a>
 </small>
 </div>

 {% endblock content %}
```

Comment: `0x82`と言うのは`すでに`の`す`等の **SJIS** 表現の第1バイトですから、保存されたファイルがUTF-8になっていないようです。使用しているエディターの設定や保存時の指定を見直して、確実にUTF-8として保存してやり直してみてください。

Comment: 試してみたところ、解決できました。

Comment: 返信が大変遅くなり、申し訳ありませんがありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

`0x82`と言うのは`すでに`の`す`等の **SJIS** 表現の第1バイトですから、保存されたファイルがUTF-8になっていないようです。
使用しているエディターの設定や保存時の指定を見直して、確実にUTF-8として保存してやり直してみてください。

---

<sup>この投稿は @OOPer さんの[コメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/52673/#comment55089_52673)などを元に編集し、[コミュニティWiki](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1583)として投稿しました。</sup>